# Asigning matrix element by list of tuple keys

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've got a 2dim database as a numpy.array (time,field values). Secondly I have a np.array of tuples, containing the coordinates of the field in the same order. What I want to do now is to reshape the database so that I can later view the map with matplotlib.imshow().
The problem is, that the field values are not distributed regularly or by a function. There is only this key list.

The C way is just running a loop. The maximum dimensions of the field are given.

```
#generating minimal dataset
data=np.random.rand(5,10)
keys=[]
maxdimx=5
maxdimy=5
for i in range(0,10):
    keys.append((np.random.random_integers(0,maxdimx-1),np.random.random_integers(0,maxdimy-1)))
#here just random keys are used, normaly there is a check for double entries

#horrible C-Style solution
def map_data(dimx,dimy,data,keys):
    maxt=data.shape[0]
    maped=np.zeros((maxt,maxdimx,maxdimy))
    for t in range(0,maxt):
        for i in range(0,len(keys)):
            maped[t,keys[i][0],keys[i][1]]=data[t,i]
    return maped
```

However this takes horrible long for big maps and longer time series.
Is there any way to put this in a vectorized function?
Is there no numpy function that can do that? Or some crazy indexing?
As the sorting is the same for each timepoint I thought there might be a possibility.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Done, minimal example is in there.

Comment: FWIW, you should get a slight speed-up by looping directly on the key tuple items, rather than doing all that indexing: `for i, (u, v) in enumerate(keys): maped[t, u, v] = data[t, i]`.

Comment: @Divakar you are right. thank you! I corrected my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for it! Here's an approach with *`crazy indexing`* aka [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
k = np.asarray(keys)
out = np.zeros((maxt,maxdimx,maxdimy))
out[np.arange(maxt)[:,None],k[:,0],k[:,1]] = data
```